# Is it in any way possible anymore to save my data?

Tags: data-recovery, 5.1-lollipop, password-protection

I have an old Allview P5 Energy which I've forgotten the password of, running Android 5.1. I was wondering if there is any possible way to recover its data. `adb devices` says the device is unauthorized and the recovery mode doesn't have a backup option. It does however have an "update from ADB". By using `adb sideload` is there any way I could bypass the password?

Comment: yes, most likely the data is FDE encrypted with default_password, therefore it should possible to root the device with modified boot.img executing custom script to delete locksettings.db and authorize adb. another option is to port TWRP recovery. SP Flash Tool or mtkclient is required